# C preprocessor #if expression

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am a bit confused on the type of expression we can use with the #IF preprocessor in the C language. I tried the following code, and it isn't working. Please explain and provide examples for expressions that can be used with the preprocessor.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int c=1;

#if c==1
    #define check(a) (a==1)?a:5
    #define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    b = check(a);
    printf("a = %d %d\n", a, TABLE_SIZE);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a copy of the C Standard or any good book provide the answer? Google for "N1570" to find a free copy of the latest draft for the C11 Standard, for example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The preprocessor cannot use variables from the C program in expressions - it can only act on preprocessor macros.  So when you try to use `c` in the preprocessor you don't get what you might expect.

However, you also don't get an error because when the preprocessor tries to evaluate an identifier that isn't defined as a macro, it treats the identifier as having a value of zero.

So when you hit this snippet:

```
#if c==1
#define check(a) (a==1)?a:5
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif
```

The `c` used by the preprocessor has nothing to do with the variable `c` from the C program.  The preprocessor looks to see if there's a macro defined for `c`.  Since there isn't, it evaluates the following expression:

```
#if 0==1
```

which is false of course.

Since you don't appear to use the variable `c` in your program, you can do the following to get behavior in line with what you're trying:

```
#define C 1

#if C==1
#define check(a) (a==1)?a:5
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif
```

(Note that I also made the macro name uppercase in keeping with convention for macro names.)

Comment: GCC and other GCC-compatible compilers support the `-Wundef` option to turn on warnings when identifiers are used within a preprocessor expression. This can help prevent accidents involving this preprocessor feature.

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor is run on the text, before any compilation is done. It doesn't know how to parse C. What you probably wanted instead of `int c=1;` was

```
#define C 1
```

and the test works the way you had it:

```
#if C == 1
```

The key here is that this is all defined *before* compile time. The preprocessor doesn't care about C variables, and certainly doesn't care what their values are.

Note that the convention is to have preprocessor macro names defined in `ALL_CAPS`.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor does not evaluate C variables. It "preprocesses" the source code before it is compiled and thus has its own language. Instead do this:

```
#define c 1

#if c==1
#define check(a) (a==1)?a:5
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
#endif
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `c` is a compiler generated symbol, `c` has no value until *run-time*, whereas preprocessor expressions are evaluated at *build-time*  (in fact as the name suggests before the compiler processes the code), so can only operate on pre-processor symbols which *do* exist at build time.

Moreover such expressions must be *compile time constants*, or in fact more exactly *preprocessing time constant*, since compiler constant expressions such as `sizeof(...)` for example are also not defined during pre-processing.