# Macro Value Changes

Tags: c

I need to explain for the MACRO define and if else conditions.

When I using the below function I get CHANGE value to 5

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHANGE var
int var;
int main()
{
    var = 5;
    printf("%d",CHANGE);

}
```

Output: `5`

But if I use like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHANGABLE_VALUE var
int var;
int main()
{
    var = 5;
    #if CHANGABLE_VALUE == 5
    printf("%d",CHANGABLE_VALUE);
    #else
    printf("There is no value");
    #endif



}
```

Output: `There is no value`

Why the #if statements not working ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C preprocessor #if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362622/c-preprocessor-if-expression)

Comment: It's called _pre_ processor because it processes items before the rest of the compilation. That is, early on in the compile-time translation phases. It cannot be used for run-time evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor definitions (aka *Macros*) are resolved during **pre-compilation** time, not during compilation time, and most certainly not during runtime, which seems to be what you're expecting.

Hence `#if CHANGABLE_VALUE == 5` is replaced with `#if var == 5` and then resolved as something which is false, so the actual code inside it is not even compiled (let alone executed).

Comment: If I use the #if var == 5 contidion, #else part is compile or not ?

Comment: @gogogo: `var` is meaningless during pre-compilation, hence `var == 5` is evaluated as false, and the `#else` part is evaluated as true (hence the code inside it is compiled and added to the executable).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to reduce code compile size with #if #else statements.

Comment: @gogogo: NP, keep in mind that those statements cannot use anything which is determined during runtime (it's a chicken/egg paradox - you cannot change the compiled code based on its output).

Comment: What is the meaning of "#if CHANGABLE_VALUE == var"? Now output: 5.

Comment: Compilation time and precompilation time are not separate in modern compilers such as GCC and Clang. Compiling a file containing the two lines `void a[3];` and `#error` with `clang -Wfatal-errors` will yield a message for the first line, showing this “compilation” error is recognized before the “precompilation” error. Explanations of preprocessing behavior should use the defined semantics, not chronology: Macro replacement never replaces the name of a variable with its value. When used in a `#if` directive, names not used in a `defined` test are replaced by `0`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between an `#if` preprocessor directive and a standard `if` statement. The preprocessor directive is evaluated before the code is actually compiled, whereas a standard `if` statement is evaluated at run-time.

Since

```
#if CHANGABLE_VALUE == 5
```

is false, the preprocessor will not include the line

```
printf("%d",CHANGABLE_VALUE);
```

in the code to be compiled. It will only include the `#else` part of the code, which is

```
printf("There is no value");
```

So, after the preprocessor phase is finished, your code will effectively look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var;
int main()
{
    var = 5;
    printf("There is no value");
}
```

Comment: This is very good explanation, thank you very much

Comment: In modern compilers, compilation and preprocessing are integrated. Compiling a file containing the two lines `void a[3];` and `#error` with `clang -Wfatal-errors` will yield a message for the first line, showing this “compilation” error is recognized before the “preprocessor” error. Explanations of preprocessing behavior should use the defined semantics, not chronology: Macro replacement never replaces the name of a variable with its value. When used in a `#if` directive, names not used in a `defined` test are replaced by `0`.