# C++ - How to use preprocessor if statements(#if, #elif, #endif) inside a macro?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, preprocessor-directive

I am currently developing a program that I intend to be portable. I have access to both Windows and macOS, and I would like to be able to debug easily on both. When error handling, I want to have debug breaks in there to make it easy(`__debugbreak()` for MSVC). Since I intend to develop and test on multiple platforms, I would like to make a macro to do something like this:

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK #ifdef DEBUG\
    #if _MSC_VER                \
        __debugbreak();         \
    #elif __GNUC__              \
        __builtin_trap();       \
    #endif                      \
#endif
```

So I can write `DEBUG_BREAK` anywhere I want to break code when debugging on any platform. When I use this macro, I get the error `'#' not expected here`.

I found two somewhat related questions:

1. [How to use #if inside #define in the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831934/how-to-use-if-inside-define-in-the-c-preprocessor)
2. [C preprocessor #if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362622/c-preprocessor-if-expression)

But neither of them answered my question, as they were trying to accomplish different things.

So my question is: How can I have preprocessor if statements inside of a macro if that is allowed? If it isn't possible, what can I do to get the same functionality this broken `DEBUG_BREAK` macro is trying to do?

Note: `DEBUG` is defined when compiling for debugging; it is not defined when compiling for release.

Comment: The preprocessor only runs once, so once it's replaced `DEBUG_BREAK` with the code you've written it stops there and now you are left with unprocessed preprocessing commands in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. But you can do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #define DEBUG_BREAK __debugbreak();
    #else
        #define DEBUG_BREAK __builtin_trap();
    #endif
#else
    #define DEBUG_BREAK /*nothing*/
#endif
```